# How to handle interactive commands using runtime.getRuntime?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have to execute a command from Java program on Unix platform.
I am using `Runtime.getRuntime()` for it.

However, the problem is that my command is interactive and asks for certain parameters at runtime. For e.g., the command is `createUser`. It asks for `userName` as the runtime.

```
bash-4.1$ createUser  

Enter the UserName:
```

How can I handle such scenario so that the user name is entered at runtime from Java program?

```
try {
    Process proc;
    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, envp);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        sb.append(s);
    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        sb.append(s);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    sb = null;
}
```

I heard that it can be done through expect. But How can I do it in Java?

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not **entirely** sure) that consuming the the two output streams needs to be done on separate threads. See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Get also the standardOutput from proc. All you write in that standardOutput goes to the command

Send the username to standardOutput and don't forget to send the \n too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what was the last line of input steam and when you detect the prompt for user input input write to the output steam your value.

```
try {
    Process proc;
    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, envp);

    final BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    final PrintWriter stdOutput = new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream());

    // read the output from the command
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals("Enter your username")) {
            stdOutput.println("MyUsername");
            stdOutput.flush();
        }

        sb.append(s);
    }

} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    sb = null;
}
```

(removed the error stream for simplicity)

Note that this works **only** if the prompt ends with a new line.

If the prompt has no new line (eg. `Username: <cursor here>`) you can try just writing the value at the start:

```
    ...
    final PrintWriter stdOutput = new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
    stdOutput.println("MyUsername");
    stdOutput.flush();
    ...
```

But if the the command clears the buffer this will no work, in that case (rare case) you have to change the way you read from the stream (eg. instead of lines, read bytes)

Comment: For some reason I dint show that you have the example where the prompt does not end with a new line. So skip the first part of the answer..